# How do you disinfect toys?

Tags: toddler, toys, sickness

My mom bought some toys from a woman with a very sick son. They had yet to find out what was wrong with him. The toys have sat in an unheated detached garage for more than 2 months. Will they be safe for an infant to play with? Some are electronic, so it is hard to get them completely sanitized.